# ProgressIndicator Spinning Wheel How To

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsprogressindicator

I would like to add a `NSProgressIndicator`.
I have a button which enable a timer, then after the delay, a method is called.

I would like to start the spinning animation when I press the button, and I would like to stop animation when the method ends.

So,  in my `.h` I added

```
NSProgressIndicator * ConnectingProgress;
```

Then in my `.m` in my button action I added

```
 [ConnectingProgress startAnimation:sender];
```

And for last at the end of my method I added

```
[ConnectingProgress stopAnimation:sender];
```

**The issues:**

1. the "sender" is not recognized in my method.
2. nothing work, also the startAnimation...

What I did wrong and How can I passtrhough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is saying you that you don't have any local variable `sender`. Pass `self` (a view controller reference) directly or declare `sender` as

```
id sender = self;
[ConnectingProgress startAnimation:sender];
```

and

```
id sender = self;
[ConnectingProgress stopAnimation:sender];
```

What's the reason to declare a `NSProgressIndicator` variable `ConnectingProgress` starting with a capital C ? The capital starting letters are used for class, categories, etc. names, use `connectingProgress` instead.

I hope the `connectingProgress` is initialized somewhere (probably at `viewDidLoad`) and added as a subView somewhere.

Comment: I edited to connectingProgress and argumented to "self" but nothing changes, I don't get error when compile but the animation doesn't start/stop. How can I do the "link" between IB & code for this object? I tried referencing outlets but the object isn't recognized

Comment: @Nono To link an outlets you need to add the `IBOutlet` keyword like `IBOutlet NSProgressIndicator * ConnectingProgress;` and then use a graphical IB outlet connection tool, check the IB documentation (note the Figure 4-6 there): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html